# Git не подсоединяется к серверу

Tags: git, phpstorm, netbeans

На собственном сервере развернули Git, порт используется не стандартный.
Создали репозиторий.
При работе через NetBeans, все работает нормально, clone, fetch, push.
Решили использовать другую среду разработки PHPStorm.
Для работы с Git дополнительно установили gitforwindows.

Теперь ситуация такая, склонировать репозиторий с сервера мы можем, а вот последующие команды не работают.
Ни push, ни fetch. Просто висит бесконечное подключение.
Такая же ситуация, если использовать другой gui например TortoiseGit.
Ошибок не выбивает.

В логах git сервера никакой информации.

Из командной строки выглядит примерно так:

```
$ git push --verbose
Pushing to git://172.16.110.5:9494/test
Looking up 172.16.110.5 ... done.
Connecting to 172.16.110.5 (port 9494) ... 172.16.110.5 done.
```

и после этого висит до бесконечности.

В Netbeans есть окно Output,

Там при выполнении git действий, например push выводит то, что Netbeans запускает.

Вот что там есть

```
git branch
git submodule status
git push git://172.16.110.5:9494/test.git refs/heads/fix-26720:refs/heads/fix-26720
```

делаем эти же команды в GitBash не прокатывает push.. висит

Подскажите где искать проблему.

Comment: Ну так с файерволом разбирайтесь, на вход соединения идут, а на выход не очень.

Comment: В процессе тестирования проводили следующие операции:
1. Отключили полностью файервол;
2. Сменили на стандартный порт 9418
3. Обновляли серверную часть Git до последней версии
4. Пробовали различные версии gitforwindows

Ни одно из этих действий не привело к результату, из NetBeans работает gitforwindows не работает push